# Active Search Bar In JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list, search

I am trying to create a search option for a list of items.  This way the user can search for a specific item within the list.  However, I am having a couple issues.  My list uses both span and images.  The jquery I created to sort sorts the list by the spans just fine however, when I try to use the active search it doesn't do anything.  Here is my sample code:

```
<input type="text" name="searchList" id="searchInput" placeholder="Type Here To Search" />
<ul id="lessonList" class="lessonlist">
<li><span class="name">Lesson 1</span>
    <img src="images/lessonFiller1.png" width="45%" height="45%"/>
</li>
<li><span class="name">Lesson 2</span>
    <img src="images/lessonFiller2.png" width="45%" height="45%"/></li>
<li><span class="name">Lesson3</span>
    <img src="images/lessonFiller3.png" width="45%" height="45%" /></li>
<li><span class="name">Lesson 4</span>
    <img src="images/lessonFiller4.png" width="45%" height="45%"/></li>
<li><span class="name">Lesson 5</span>
    <img src="images/lessonFiller5.png" width="45%" height="45%"/></li>
</ul>
```

Again my sort jQuery works just fine:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
var desc = $(this).hasClass("asc"),
    list = $("#lessonList");
list.append(list.children().get().sort(function(a, b) {
    var aProp = $(a).find("span.name").text(),
        bProp = $(b).find("span.name").text();
    return (aProp > bProp ? 1 : aProp < bProp ? -1 : 0) * (desc ? -1 : 1);
}));
$(this).toggleClass("desc", desc)
       .toggleClass("asc", !desc)
       .siblings().removeClass("asc desc");
e.preventDefault();});
```

However, when I try to use the input to create an active search nothing happens.  Here is its code:

```
$('#searchInput').keyup(function(){

//var that = this, $allListElements = $('ul > li');
var valThis = $(this).val();
var list = $('ul li span');

list.each(function(){
 var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
    (text.indexOf(valThis) == 0) ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();});});
```

What am I doing wrong?  Is this even something I can do?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues,

1. where are you including your script? in the head or in the last of body?If script is loaded before html dom elements are created, then put your keyup binding inside ready function.
2. hide li not span. Use parent() to show/hide.

Below code should work and link is https://jsfiddle.net/4pbp5dhr/

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
 var desc = $(this).hasClass("asc"),
list = $("#lessonList");
list.append(list.children().get().sort(function(a, b) {
var aProp = $(a).find("span.name").text(),
    bProp = $(b).find("span.name").text();
    return (aProp > bProp ? 1 : aProp < bProp ? -1 : 0) * (desc ? -1 : 1);
}));
$(this).toggleClass("desc", desc)
   .toggleClass("asc", !desc)
   .siblings().removeClass("asc desc");
 //e.preventDefault();

//Move the search input inside ready
$('#searchInput').keyup(function(){

//var that = this, $allListElements = $('ul > li');
var valThis = $(this).val();
console.log(valThis);
var list = $('ul li span');

list.each(function(){
   var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
   (text.indexOf(valThis) == 0) ? $(this).parent().show() :      $(this).parent().hide();});
});

});
```

I have commented preventDefault().

Comment: That works very well thank you!  I do have one more question though.  How can I make it so it searches the body of the span?  For example I can only type "lesson" other wise if I type "1" the entire list disappears.

Comment: Never mind I was able to figure out a solution.  All I had to do was change the == 0 to >= 0 and that did the trick.

Comment: i guess better way to do is > -1. this should be faster.